# Not sure if "see" is used intransitively or transitively

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses, adverbial-phrases, direct-objects

[image]

Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged

> **Much that dog and see won't he come along** ―Horace Kephart

Does the sentence mean

*If he won't come along, much that dog and see*

("see" is used here intransitively, "if he won't come along" being an adverbial clause)

or

*Much that dog and see if he won't come along*

("see" is used here transitively, "if he won't come along" being a nominal clause)

Comment: I suspect it is archaic. In today's English it would be meaningless gibberish.

Comment: I find both that use of _much_ , and the syntax, strange, but I would understand it to mean "See if he won't come along" (i.e. he probably will).

Comment: @avant-garde Have you a copy of that dictionary. and if so when was it published?

Comment: @avant-garde. What is your interest in an archaic use of "much"? Are you studying earlier stages of the language?

Comment: _Try God & see won’t He not just bless you, but literally BLOW…YOUR…MIND!_ modern religious website

Comment: Thank you for your help. @Billj I have the dictionary. I captured it myself. COPYRIGHT 2002 BY MERRIAM_WEBSTER, INCORPORATED. I have been studying English itself which I have interest in. While looking up a dictionary (regarding "much"), I stumbled across the example sentence. While reading the example sentences in the dictionary, I was curious to find out what the sentence means.

Comment: @avant-garde - Webster's Third International Dictionary was published in September 1961, even if the copyright notice you saw is dated 2002. This does not affect the subject of the question.

Comment: @BillJ - archaic in Britain, and regional in the US, I suspect. Horace Kephart (1862-1931) was a noted collector of US Southern Appalachian sayings from around 1900 to his death, and [a lexicon](https://uknowledge.uky.edu/upk_linguistics/1/) has been prepared based on his material. The Oxford English Dictionary gives a similar definition to Webster's for 'much' _(verb) trans. To make much of; to pet, fondle, caress_, and the only usage examples are dated 1736 and 1848 (not 1948, as I mistyped earlier). . Webster's Third New International was published in 1961.

Comment: There are many sayings and speech forms that were common in English of earlier centuries that are now only found as restricted, regional US usages. There are [some people in isolated communities](https://www.openculture.com/2019/12/the-americans-who-still-speak-with-regional-british-english-accents.html) that speak what some have called 'Elizabethan' English.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Thanks to you, considering your example sentence from modern religious website, I guess I'll take it that "If he won't come along" is a nominal clause, being the object of see.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for saying that. Webster's Thrid New International Dictionary says it (much as a verb) is dialect, not archaic. As you can see in the picture, "dial" means dialect in the dictionary.

Comment: My advice to you is simple: don't use it!

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you very much. Despite your reply being the top, I was the last to see it.

Comment: @avant-garde - maybe dialect in US English, but **definitely**  very archaic in British English. Webster's dictionaries are American, even if that one calls itself 'international'.

Comment: Could **won't he come along** be interrogative?  If so, we should be able to find  something like "Go down to the general store and see *don't they have any 6d nails*".

Comment: @BillJ. I'll keep that in mind. I know the immense difference between understanding and using language. I was about to understand it, not to use it. I was just curious to find out what that means exactly.

Comment: @Michael Harvey. I should think old-fashioned turns of phrase do not necessarily mean gibberish. Even if it's dialect, it has value/meaning to someone in a particular area/group, which should not be excluded. Even though it's peripheral, it's well worth understanding because the universe has no center.

Comment: @avant-garde No: this site is for learners who want to learn English as it is used today. It's more than peripheral, it's archaic at least it is in BrE.

Comment: I doubt that even in Appalachia today, they'd use "much" this way. Even though there are remnants of Elizabethan English.  That definition you found avant-garde is very interesting. //People can ask about archaic language, why not? Speaking four different languages myself, I really dislike being told what I should or should not be interested in or look up.

Comment: What is really cool is that the word "much" in that definition as a verb has: he/she muches or muched or he's or she's muching. How is that not cool? Wow. Every day I am surprised by my own language. avant-garde, don't beat yourself up. Your question was really interesting for me. As they say: Onward and upward.

Comment: @BillJ Just because someone asks about something and it turns out to be archaic, old-fashioned, Old English or LA ghetto, does not mean that are planning  forsooth to **use** it. .

Comment: @Lambie. As a learner of a foreign language, I cannot help consenting to your thought. I cannot help but like your attitude of openness toward language. That expression "How is that not cool?" is super beautiful.

Comment: @BillJ. I'm also a learner of International English. Could it be that a learner has no right to understand the sentence, which is dialect at least in AmE according to the authoritative dictionary? Was I wrong to have the will to comprehend it as a learner? I don't think so. It apppears that while a lot of people are trying to enlighten me about what the sentence is, you seem to be trying to stop me from understanding it. I was taught that If you're a learner of any language, keep in mind that each language/dialect has value. That's really all that there is to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb **see** is complemented by a clause in this rural dialect construction. Call that clause an object, and see don't I object.

Here's a similar construction from Zora Neale Hurston's 1925 play *Spunk* which is set in the rural south of the United States:

> Mrs. Watson: Howd'd do, brother Bishop?
>
> Bishop: I ain't none of your brother. Your brother is out hunting coconuts. I'm going to have you up in church **and see can't they handle you**.

And from a posting from *[The New York Observer](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_York_Observer/NRVQAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and%20see%20won%27t%20he%22&pg=RA1-PA715&printsec=frontcover)*, November 25th, 1909:

> Odds and Ends
>
> PIGS AND PAIN
>
> A barnyard musing when confronted by a number of little pigs after reading a newspaper account of Mrs Stetson's real troubles:
>
> Dear Mother Eddy says pain is not real--
> Just pinch piggy's tail **and see won't he squeal!**
>
> Moral: Either piggy can't fake, or "error of the mortal mind", "false belief" crept into piggy's tail .

[The reference is to Mary Baker Eddy, who founded the Christian Science religion in 1879].

And from the 1948 novel *High John the Conqueror* by John Walter Wilson

> "Mr John goin' to be headin' back this way before long," Lula said. "Why don't you watch out for him on the road **and see won't he stop when he come by** ?"
>
> "Howcome?" Joe Coby asked ...

Comment: "Call that clause an object, and see don't I object" certainly doesn't look like normal English to me. I don't understand what it means anyway. What is a non-native speaker expected to make of it?

Comment: That was tongue-in-cheek. These rural dialect constructions could be paraphrased "and see if ..."

Answer (score 1):

It's distracting that the cited example features an *extremely* unusual / dialectal use of ***much*** as a verb (meaning *to **make much** of, to **make a fuss** of, to "pet" warmly / enthusiastically*<sup>1</sup>).

But the actual question concerns the verb ***see***. Where I'd say that...

> *See if he won't come along*
> is colloquial / dialectal phrasing for...
> *Let's see if he will come along*

...with the strong implication *The dog probably **will** want to come with us if you [jolly him along](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/jolly-along)*. [Here's another example](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22i%20will%20see%20this%20wild%20man%22%20%22see%20if%20i%20don%27t%22) of effectively the same usage (also dialectal / colloquial, also featuring near-meaningless negation)...

> *I will see this wild man, if it's in the power of bones and muscles to carry me within eyeshot of him. Now, **see if I don't***.

I'm not sure transitive/intransitive is a useful concept here. I might say the usages are "imperative".

---

<sup>1</sup> The full OED says this use of ***much*** is *chiefly U.S. regional and Caribbean.*

Comment: I'd have to disagree that "see if he won't come along" is non-standard dialect, though I'd agree it's colloquial, whereas "... see won't he come along" is definitely dialect.

Comment: I'd say the *negation* in such contexts is "dialectal" rather than "colloquial", but there's a huge overlap between those two terms, and there might be a AmE/BrE usage split anyway. The main point is I believe the OP would be unwise to copy virtually *anything* from the cited text - but in particular, he should be careful regarding the non-standard verb ***much***, and the inversion / negation of ***see won't he...*** The "standard" form here would be *...[let's] see if he **will** come along*.

Comment: **Ask him, and see if he won't come along** may strike your BrE ears as dialectal but it's perfectly idiomatic AmE.  I am not advising OP to copy anything and understand that is also your stance, which is a perfectly reasonable stance.

Comment: It wouldn't be easy to find supporting evidence, but if you say that negation is "perfectly idiomatic AmE", I'm hardly gonna argue the toss. But I think we Brits are only likely to encounter it in (informal) "regional / dialectal" *Irish* contexts. Possibly also Welsh and/or West Country mainland dialects, I'm not sure.

Comment: The Philadelphia dialect that I speak (subgroup of US Mid-Atlantic) was much influenced by Irish English.